# Recommended Tape archiving software

Tags: tape

I'm looking for an archiving software (for Windows) which will allow me to archive files to a automated tape library.

I've looked at EMC NetWorker, and it does do what I want, but I require one that comes with an SDK so that I can integrated it with an enterprise application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously there's LOTS of options out there and you don't mention your budget but I like both Symantec NetBackup and Commvault's Simpana, both pretty high-end but they're fast, reliable and very flexible - though far from free.

Comment: But all these options come without SDKS...

Comment: I've decided to use EMC Networker and develop a wrapper around its CLI interface